# Keras autoencoder simple example has a strange output

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to run a simple autoencoder, all the training input is the same. The training data features are equal to 3, and the hidden layer has 3 nodes in it. I train the autoencoder with that input, then I try to predict it (encode/decode) again (so if the autoencoder passes everything as is without any changes it should work)

Anyway, that's not the case, and I am a sturggling a bit to understand why. I am not sure if it's something wrong in my code, or in my understanding of the autoencdoer implementation. Here is the code for reference.

P.S. I played around with the number of epoches, number of examples in the training set, the batch size, made the training data values between 0-1, and kept track of the loss value, but that didn't help either.

`

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np 
# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 3

x_train=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
in= Input(shape=(3,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(in)
decoded = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(in, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
                epochs=100,
                batch_size=4)
autoencoder.predict(x_train)
```

`

The output I get should be the same as the input (or at least close) but I get this instead)

```
`Out[180]: 
array([[ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ],
       [ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ],
       [ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ],
       [ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ],
       [ 0.80265796,  0.89038897,  0.9100889 ]], dtype=float32)`
```

Any help would be appreciated, most likely I understood something wrong so hopefully this question is not that hard to answer.

Answer (score 8):

The error is here `decoded = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(encoded)`.

You shouldn't use `sigmoid` activation, because it will limit the output in range (0, 1), replace the `sigmoid` with `linear` or just remove it, and you can add more epochs, e.g. train 1000 epochs. In this setting, I get what you need

```
[[ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]
 [ 0.98220336  1.98066235  2.98398876]]
```

In addition, you should replace the input `in` with another name, as it is a `keyword` in Python :-).

Answer (score 2):

After apply @danche suggestion following is the updated code and results, I got the results after increasing the epocs  = 10000

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import numpy as np
# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 3

x_train=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
input = Input(shape=(3,))
encoded = Dense(encoding_dim, activation='relu')(input)
decoded = Dense(3, activation='linear')(encoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,epochs=10000,batch_size=4)
print(autoencoder.predict(x_train))



Epoch 10000/10000
8/8 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 2.4463e-04     
[[ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]
 [ 0.99124289  1.98534203  2.97887278]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input data is not normalized. After normalization as below, you can get the correct output.

```
x_train=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
x_train=keras.utils.normalize(x_train)  #newly added line
 ....
 ....
```

Comment: Not really an issue

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly build an autoencoder in Keras using the Sequential model. So I am no sure [**that the example you are referring to**](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) is exactly the "simplest possible autoencoder" you can create, as the article's author claims. Here's how I would do it:

```
from keras.models                   import Sequential
from keras.layers                   import Dense 

import numpy as np 

# this is the size of our encoded representations
encoding_dim = 3

np.random.seed(1)  # to ensure the same results

x_train=np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])

autoencoder = Sequential([ 
              Dense(encoding_dim,input_shape=(3,)), 
              Dense(encoding_dim)
])

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')

autoencoder.fit(x_train, x_train,
            epochs=127,
            batch_size=4, 
            verbose=2)

out=autoencoder.predict(x_train)
print(out)
```

When running this example you get

```
 ....
 Epoch 127/127
 - 0s - loss: 1.8948e-14
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 1.  2.  3.]]
```

which is kind of nice...